# Composite foreign key columns in GORM

Tags: grails, mapping, foreign-keys, grails-orm, composite

I need to customize the column names for composite foreign keys in GORM, and I didn't find any document that shows how to do it. I know how to customize PK columns, and how to customize a single-column FK, but not multi-column FK. Is it possible at all?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

A domain class with composite id must implement the `Serializable` interface.

```
class Person implements Serializable {
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the "id: composite" construct in your object mapping closure.

I have to leave for work, so here it is in brief:

```
class Person {
  String firstName
  String lastName

    static mapping = { 
        id composite:['firstName', 'lastName'] 
    } 
}
```

[Grails: Object Relational Mapping](http://www.grails.org/doc/1.0.x/guide/5.%20Object%20Relational%20Mapping%20(GORM).html)

Comment: He is asking about foreign keys, not the primary key